# Codingbat challenge: sameEnds Stream API Solution

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, java-stream

Given the task [*sameEnds*](https://codingbat.com/prob/p134300) from ***CodingBat***:

> Return true if the group of `N` numbers at the start and end of the array are the same. For example, with `{5, 6, 45, 99, 13, 5, 6}`, the ends are the same for `n=0` and `n=2`, and false for `n=1` and `n=3`. You may assume that `n` is in the range `0..nums.length` inclusive.
>
> ```
> sameEnds([5, 6, 45, 99, 13, 5, 6], 1) → false
> sameEnds([5, 6, 45, 99, 13, 5, 6], 2) → true
> sameEnds([5, 6, 45, 99, 13, 5, 6], 3) → false
> ```

My solution to this problem passes the vast majority of the tests, but not all of them:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
  
  if (nums.length >= len * 2) {
    for (int i = 0, j = nums.length - 1 ; i < len && len > 0; i++, j--) {
       if (nums[i] != nums[j]) {
         return false;
       }
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

My questions are the following:

1. What can be done in order to fix my solution?
2. Is it possible to solve this task using ***Stream API*** ?

Comment: What test cases are failing?

Comment: The spec doesn't prohibit `len` from being greater than `nums.length / 2`. The start and end can overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`allMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) operation in order to implement it with streams.

This solution passes all test cases on *CodingBat*:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
    return java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0, len)
        .allMatch(n -> nums[n] == nums[nums.length - (len - n)]);
}
```

A fix to your imperative solution might look like this:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
    for (int i = 0, j = nums.length - 1 - (len - 1); i < len; i++, j++) {
        if (nums[i] != nums[j]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I removed the wrapping if condition because when `nums.length >= len * 2` is evaluated to `false` it means that *subarrays* that need to be compared overlap, but it doesn't automatically mean that these *subarrays* are equal.

Condition `len > 0` is redundant because it is guaranteed to be in the range `[0,nums.length]`.

Variable `j` that denotes position in the tail *subarray* has been initialized to `nums.length - 1 - (len - 1)` - last valid index minus *subarray's* length. And the so-called *increment statement* of the `for` loop was changed from `j--` to `j++`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in method [Arrays.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int%5B%5D,int,int,int%5B%5D,int,int)) if you are using Java 9 or higher:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
    return Arrays.equals(nums, 0, len, nums, nums.length - len, nums.length);
}
```